# E: Package 'libtool-bin' has no installation candidate

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-mint, apt-get

due installing the prerequisites for a software, which is explained step by step [here](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/ESP8266#ESP8266-ConnectingESP8266toPC(Linux)) , when I enter this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libtool-bin
```

I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libtool-bin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
libtool:i386 libtool

E: Package 'libtool-bin' has no installation candidate
```

I have tried some advices such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164935/unavailable-repository) or [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/271605), but non of them solved the problem.

thank in advance

Comment: Did you check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/514852/how-to-solve-package-issues-dependencies

Comment: Which distribution and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: @user2676140 I had checked it before, and checked it again after you sent the link, but I didn't find any solution to my problem. could you please explain more if you think the problem is the same?

Comment: @jcbermu I'm using linux-mint, the kernel version is 3.13.0-24-generic. I have entered apt-get update and apt-get dist-upgrade too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`libtool-bin` is only available in *Linux Mint Sarah* (version 18) as you can see in this [forum](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libtool-bin).

Previous Mint versions don't include the package on their repositories.

If you are using a Mint version different from *18* then you have to compile manually the package downloading it from [GNU libtool](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/).

Comment: [Here](http://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/244302-trying-install-libtool-source-newbie.html) is a guide for `libtool 2.4`.  In the `wget`line change it to the URL of the latest version and give it a try.

Comment: if I enter ./configure && make && make install ... it is over?! I ask that because I see some "failed" rows in make check.

Comment: Verify the failed rows in `make` because they indicate problems during the compilation.